# Filtering HTML inside data of HandOnTable

Tags: javascript, handsontable

We use handsontable with [filtering](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.14.2/demo-filtering.html). To make the elements inside the table nicer we'd like to use some html (so you can create "badges" etc).

Here is an example:
[image]

The issue is that, when we filter, we see the value as raw html. Is there any way to either:

1) specify a value inside the html to be considered as the "stringified" version of that, so that it does not cause issues in showing values

2) alternatively be able to render directly the html in the list of values (so we'd have our "badges"

Thank you

SN

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: I use a custom cell renderer that will generate all the fancy html, while the value will be stripped of all unnecessary html stuff. This way I can see properly the elements in the filter.